# Readme files for Meteor 1.0.2 missing by design?

Tags: meteor

Curious to know why none of the core packages for Meteor 1.0.2 have readme files associated with them. At least the ones I'm presently working with such as accounts-base and oauth and service-configuration and google. Is this by design? Is there a similar file/resource listed elsewhere that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Meteor Core packages have a readme. They vary in details: from one-paragraph describing the purpose of the package, to a detailed tutorial and a high-level overview.

A package you mentioned, accounts-base has a short readme: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-base

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @imslavko - it seems like those readme files are in the git repo but not available on my local machine with my most recent install of the platform - good to know.